# how to avoid re-implementing functionality to avoid double testing

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

we developed a component with TDD. This component has a persistence backend.
We chose to implement it using SQLite.
The backend can Save() and Load() a collection of items.
So to write test the Load() function we filled the SQLite database with SQL code in our test, so we don't use the Save() function so that we don't test it along the Load() test.
So basically we re-implemented code from our tests that is also in our component.
Like I said, we are doing this so that we can only test isolated functions.

This has a (very) sour taste to it.

- re-implementing production code
- tests depend on the implementation detail SQLite

My question is, is it worth it to make such an effort to avoid testing our Load() and Save() functions together?

Are there any other methodologies used by our fellow stackoverflow members?

Comment: This does indeed not sound like a unit test. Unit tests are meant to be quick and repeatable; manually changing the database per test should not be done. A unit test of Load() should only verify (e.g. via mocking) that the next method gets called (in this case `sqlite3_exec`, I think). Maybe include the Load and Save methods in your question for more specific help?

Comment: What does the component do / what are you testing?  Is always a great starting point.

Comment: The code is rather small. It takes a list of objects and saves them in some way. In this case to the SQLite DB. To me it feels like a unit, it's a small test too.

Comment: small like it's 4 lines of test and 10 lines of code that's tested.
I don't have the feeling that the code and the tests don't qualify as unit / unit tests.
Unless the persistence is disqualifying the code as unit per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically we re-implemented code from our tests that is 
>   also in our component

from my point of view this is not true.

while the "persistence backend" must be generic (i.e. can save data for every customer) the sql-code in your test must not be generic. A concrete example is enough in the testcode.

```
testLoadExistingCustomer() {
  sql.exec("delete from customers where id=1");

  sql.exec("Insert into Customers(id,name) values(1, 'Smith')");

  Customer cust = repository.loadByid(1);
  assert(.....)
}

testSaveNewCustomer() {
  sql.exec("delete from customers where id=1");

  Customer cust = new Customer(1, "Smith");
  repository.save(customer);

  int count = sql.exec("select count(*) from Customers where id=1 and name='Smith'");

  assert(1,count)
}
```

[update after comment]

my answer was a white box test about your original question concerning code duplication. Here is an alternative as black-box test

I usually test my persistence/serialisation  by veirfying that two inverse functions save+load get the same content. Since i also implement a toString Method for debugging puposes such a test becomes:

```
testSavePlusLoadCustomer() {
  Customer cust = new Customer(1, "Smith");
  repository.save(customer);

  Customer loadedCustomer = repository.loadByid(1);
  assertEquals(cust.toString(), loadedCustomer.toString());
}
```

This is not clean because this test (like many other integratoin-tests) has several reasons to fail or being a false positive (either save or load not working correctly, testdata missing one attribute set, toString() missing one attribute in output) but it is good as a regression test (make shure that previously working code is not broken)

Comment: I understand what you say, but I believe the test shouldn't even know how the backend works. like a blackbox.
So when I change the persistence layer the tests would fail.
But I guess that's another point. grey-box vs black-box tests.

Comment: That looks reasonable. That way you can replace the component that is using other technologies, without changing the tests.
It's not clean, yes... but looking at the pros and cons it looks OK for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it up to you, there is always a trade-off. My personal thoughts...

For Unit tests it might be worth having these as two separate test cases (Single Responsibility). This makes the tests easier to read and maintain, and will also help isolate a test failure i.e you will know if it fails during load or save.
Although by testing the expected bahaviour rather then individual methods this might provide a different perspective

It its a unit test, then avoid actually writing to the database, maybe look at using an in-memory version.

Use the real database in an Integration or System test - These can be higher level, where you might combine the testing of reading and writing into a single feature or scenario (Test Pyramid).

If there is duplication in your test code, seek to remove it (DRY principle), by using test data builders than can be re-used to set up tests.

One other point, think about what your test is actually testing, i.e. Sounds like you might be testing if SQLite can read and write data, whereas maybe you need to test the data coming out is correct, so aging using a Unit/Integration test combo, you may be able to extract away form the DB at unit test level - So test the expected behaviour not the implementation.

Comment: we are already using an in-memory SQLite database. But still we want to know if our queries are correct and populate our result objects correctly.
Maybe we should be using some declarative(?) persistence layer instead of hand crafted SQL.
We want to have the unit tests separately like you said, so we can find errors.
We've come across this a few times, and I guess we're not the only ones. I wonder how others solve this.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is it worth it to make such an effort to avoid testing our Load() and Save() functions together?

Probably not.

There are different, less expensive ways of separating the testing of load and save.

The most common one is to change the focus of your testing from the data to the orchestration.  So you would use a test double to stand in for your data store, and when unit testing Load you would pay attention to whether or not the right messages were sent to the test double, without worrying about the messages that should be sent when storing the data.  Likewise, when unit testing Store, you concentration on whether those messages are sent, ignoring the load messages.

This is a common approach when using the ports and adapters design.  You arrange your code so that the part which is difficult to test is "so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies", and then replace that part with a test double that *is* easy to test.

Later on, when you are integration or end to end testing, you hook up to a real data store and ensure that you really can read out the data that you are writing.

But if that doesn't make sense, or is still too expensive, or requires deficient trade offs somewhere else, then don't do it.

Comment: I also thought it would make sense to use something other than hand written SQL. Some tool that will make it unnecessary to test the persistence layer.
Like you suggested - make it so simple that testing is simple. Or even unnecessary.
Good point!